# Example using go-assets in gin

Tags: go, assets, go-gin

I'd like to have a single binary for a go-app, rather than having to bundle static files alongside the deployment.

I'm using a function like this to access PNGs I'm loading:

```
func getFileList(dir string) (fileList []os.FileInfo, err error) {
    // USAGE: 
    //    fileList,_ := getFileList(PNG_DIR)
    f, err := os.Open(PNG_DIR)
    defer f.Close()
    checkErr(err)
    fileList, err = f.Readdir(0)
    checkErr(err)
    return fileList, err
}
```

I take this list of files and serve it on a static endpoint, with some logic.

I have read the following documentation for using go-assets

- https://github.com/jessevdk/go-assets-builder/blob/master/builder.go
- https://github.com/jessevdk/go-assets-builder
- https://github.com/jessevdk/go-assets/blob/master/generate.go

As well as this gin specific example:

- https://github.com/gin-gonic/gin/blob/master/examples/assets-in-binary/assets.go
- https://github.com/jessevdk/go-assets/blob/master/example_test.go
- https://github.com/gin-gonic/gin/tree/master/examples/assets-in-binary

Which contains the following example:

> ### Prepare Packages
>
> go get github.com/gin-gonic/gin go get
>   github.com/jessevdk/go-assets-builder
>
> ### Generate assets.go
>
> go-assets-builder html -o assets.go
>
> ### Build the server
>
> go build -o assets-in-binary
>
> ### Run
>
> ./assets-in-binary

However, it's not clear to me how to call this file I have built.  For example, What do I change in my `getFileList()` function to now point to whatever I built in the binary, what is it even called and how would I know that?

Answer (score 1):

Usually on gin you would use `router.Statuc(path, dir)` however you said you first load a list of files and I guess you will later use `http.ServeFile`.

With `go-bindata` you have all the files already inside the executable, you can access them using the `Asset(file)` function...

Basically this is a very simple static handler for gin:

```
func StaticHandler(c *gin.Context) {
      p := c.Param("filepath")
      data, err := Assets(p)
      if err != nil { return }
      c.Writer.Write(data)
}
```

You can register the static handler into your router:

`router.GET("/static/*filepath", StaticHandler)`

This allows to access static resources the following way: `/static/css/style.css` and will load the file `css/style.css`

You could get the list of files inside your folder, create a map and use that map for the static handler (to limit what files are accesed)

Comment: This example gives me `undefined: Asset` This needs to be declared outside of the staticHandler function?  The example seems a bit involved https://github.com/gin-gonic/gin/blob/master/examples/assets-in-binary/assets.go#L13

Comment: yeah, weird, I understand assets.go is created by the build command, but even while my build command is successful, it doesn't look like the `var Assets = ...` is getting sourced in correctly.  It is still a part of package main and everything.  This is odd.

Comment: Usually the generated output is created with `main` package, you can change that package tho https://github.com/a-urth/go-bindata/blob/master/config.go#L28

Comment: Got it---Assets, not Asset. :)